# Escape backslash in C#

Tags: c#, json, regex, escaping

I am de-serializing a JSON file, and in the JSON I have patterns stored like, `* are you *`. This pattern should match with `How are you?`. I want to match the patterns with Regex in C#.

I tried:

1. Edited the patterns in JSON. Tried converting `* are you *` to `\w* are you \w*`. Does not work with de-serialization.
2. Before applying Regex, tried to replace `"*"` with `@"\w*"` and `"\\w*"`. But both the times the resultant pattern becomes `\\w*` which Regex is unable to match.

Please help. Ask if you need any clarification. N.B. Can't use any third-party library.

Comment: Are you looking at the strings in the Visual Studio debugger? That one will actually show you strings as if you entered them as string literals in C#, so it will double `\` inside the string. Note also that `\` is also an escape character in JSON, so in JSON you'd have to write `\\w`.

Comment: Can you expand your question to a [mcve] that shows the JSON and how you are deserializing it?

Comment: @Joey Sorry, I was checking it in the debugger. And the flow got stuck somewhere else. Thanks for the insight!